# web-push unknown issue, WebPushError "Received unexpected response code" 400

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

During the development of **[web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push)** with GCM and chrome. I've encountered this issue recently (couple hours ago everything still working fine)

I am not sure if this is happen due to some changes at GCM or a downtime of the cloud... Any information will be appreciated.

My code

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({
    title: 'notification title',
    body: 'message body'
});
webPush.sendNotification(params.endpoint, {
    userPublicKey: params.userPublicKey,
    userAuth: params.userAuth,
    payload: payload
}).then(function (res) { 
    // console.log of stuff
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Trace:

```
{
  WebPushError: Received unexpected response code
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/***/pwa/node_modules/web-push /index.js:264:20)
  at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'WebPushError',
  message: 'Received unexpected response code',
  statusCode: 400,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
     date: 'Wed, 04 May 2016 11:35:13 GMT',
     expires: 'Wed, 04 May 2016 11:35:13 GMT',
    'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
     server: 'GSE',
    'alternate-protocol': '443:quic',
    'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25"',
    'accept-ranges': 'none',
     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
     connection: 'close'
  },
  body: 'JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 467.\n' 
}
```

Comment: I suggest using services like [pushpad-node](https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-node) if you don't want to mess with low level details

Comment: Can you show us an example of your payload?

Comment: @collimarco Your suggest seem  very interesting to me. But sadly the requirement is make a dedicated push module for the project... 3rd service will be denied right away :(

Comment: @Marco, I've add the script for generating payload. It is a stringified JSON.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the GCM key correctly? Is there any chance there's a newline character in the GCM key you're setting?

Comment: Hey, I'm getting the same error, tried everything possible, is your issue resolved?

Comment: @anshulix, Hi, it was busy days, and I did not have any chance to update this question,but for short there are many causes for this to happen.... In my case this, this was cause by the malformed data, when either the `endpoint`, `userPublicKey`, `userAuth` or `payload` got bad encrypted/decrypted. --- In other words, I will suggest you to first check the `payload` make sure it is a "String". Then debug  `endpoint`, `userPublicKey` or `userAuth` before execute web-push make sure they are still exactly the same when you received it.

Comment: @Linh, it shows weird behaviour, worked well for sometime and then suddenly started showing this error again. I think I'll have to roll back to my native GCM implementation.

Comment: @Linh, what do you mean by "userPublicKey or userAuth ... make sure they are still exactly the same when you received it" ? ... I'm not receiving them from anywhere, I'm generating them from the subscriptionObject on the frontend. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870838/webpusherror-and-unauthorizedregistration-when-try-to-send-push-notification-to)

Answer (score 2):

@Lihn, paste here your payload. From error the message, it seems like you are sending a malformed json message.

You can use [this service](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to check for syntax problems in your json.

The [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text) states that a status code 400 means the json message could not be parsed.

Comment: Hi! My payload is not a JSON. It is either a stringified JSON or simply a string. Something like this `"notification message"` --- As mentioned in the question on both FireFox and Chrome, all were working well until recently it is broken for GCM on Chrome. --- Still thank you for your time and the answer! :)

Comment: Try to set the headers to 'Content-type': 'application/json' ?

Comment: Already did `'Content-type': 'application/json'` , also I've tried without `payload`, `userPublicKey` and `userAuth`  none of them work.

Comment: GCM clearly [documents][1] error status 400 as a json that could not be parsed, so my advice is to debug the json string.
  
    [1]: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text

Comment: Thanks again for the url of documentation, sadly it mention the error only apply for JSON request. And for `web-push` I only use text as payload. --- But I guess I could check the other fields like `enpoint`... etc... --- Please edit your answer and provide the link to GCM documentation, I will upvote it (since it is useful for me).

Comment: Is this occuring on a firefox endpoint or Chrome?

If it's firefox a non 2XX http status code means there was either a problem contacting the push service or something wrong with the request.

If it's Chrome, then I'm not sure, normally GCM returns an error code in the JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send push notifications using web-push, try regenerating the public and private key using #npm run web-push generate-vapid-keys. Try again by replacing these keys. Good Luck.

Comment: that will invalidate all the subscriptions i believe