# WebPushError and UnauthorizedRegistration when try to send push notification to Chrome and Opera, Firefox is OK

Tags: firebase, web-push

I managed to run a working example for sending web-push notifications - subscribe user for push notifications, get the endpoint, generate the two `browser` keys from the subscription object - `p256dh` and `auth`. On the server side I generate the `VAPID` keys.
So, with all these I call `sendNotification` on the `web-push` Node.js package, and also - I'm passing a payload.

On Firefox - I get the notification with the payload.

On Chrome and Opera I get `WebPushError: Received unexpected response code` and furthermore - `UnauthorizedRegistration` and `Error 400`.

The server side code I'm using to send the stuff is:

```
// import our web-push package ..
var webPush = require('web-push');

webPush.setGCMAPIKey('MY_GCM_SENDER_ID');

// we generated the VAPID keys ..
var vapidKeys = {
    "publicKey": "...",
    "privateKey": "..."
};

// set our VAPID credentials ..
webPush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:{my email}',
  vapidKeys.publicKey,
  vapidKeys.privateKey
);

var device_endpoint = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/...";
var device_key = "...";
var device_auth = "...";


/*
 * Sending the notification ..
 */
webPush.sendNotification(
    {
        endpoint: device_endpoint,
        keys: {
            p256dh: device_key,
            auth: device_auth
        }
    },
    'My payload',
    {
        TTL: 86400, // 24 hours ..
    }
)
.then(function() {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unsuccessful');
    console.log(err);
});
```

I also have put MY_GCM_SENDER_ID as `gcm_sender_id` in `manifest.json` file.

I took it from `https://console.firebase.google.com/` - created a project and got the `Sender ID` from `Settings - Cloud Messaging`.

Instructions for this I read here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

So ... Could anyone help to identify what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that I'm trying this from my local machine? ... Cause I have a publicly visible server with domain on it, but wanted to test everything locally before deploy there.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out. And now I'm sending `PUSH` with payload successfully :)

The problem was that when I was registering for `PUSH` - I was doing it like this:

```
reg.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true
})
```

When I did it like this:

```
reg.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: new urlBase64ToUint8Array([VAPID public key)
})
```

then it worked just fine. Now I'm able to send normal PUSH or PUSH with payload, with no problems.

More info:

1. https://rossta.net/blog/using-the-web-push-api-with-vapid.html
2. https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-02/01-subscribing-a-user/

And regarding all the tutorials that tells you to use only the `userVisibleOnly` property...that doesn't work. I don't know why they would be recommending this.

Comment: note that only supplying the userVisibleOnly property should work if you are not using encryption and not supplying a payload with the notification. So that might explain why some of the tutorials you were reading did not cover the need for the applicationServerKey property.

Answer (score 0):

- One of situations you will meet this error described following:

  [One will produce the wrong process](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638924&can=2&q=638924&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

  And Google tutorial also mention following:

  `open DevTools (Right Click > Inspect) and go to the Application panel, click the Service Workers tab and check the Update on Reload checkbox. When this checkbox is enabled the service worker is forcibly updated every time the page reloads.`
- If you want to push notification with payload in website:

  Add `applicationServerKey` in when you `subscribe`
- If you add `applicationServerKey` in when `subscribe`

  1. Keys generated by openssl not work for me.
  2. Keys generated by vapid not work for me.
  3. **Keys generated by website mentioned in google tutorial works.**
- Workable keys generator:
  [Workable keys generator](https://web-push-codelab.appspot.com/)
- Workable google tutorial:
  [Workable google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/)

**Conclution**

1. I add `applicationServerKey` and cause errors
2. I use `Workable keys generator` but still errors
3. I follow `Google tutorial` to update service worker to prevent some error
4. works